# How can i access CVV in frames react?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, stripe-payments

I'm utlizing frames react for payment.But the issue is i'm not able to access the CVV.Is there any solution so that i can access and send it to backend ?

I got the token,last4digit, expiryDate but can't access the CVV. Is there any solution out there so that i can resolve this issue

```
               <Frames
                  config={{
                    debug: true,
                    publicKey: "public-key-here",
                    localization: {
                      cardNumberPlaceholder: "",
                      expiryMonthPlaceholder: "",
                      expiryYearPlaceholder: "",
                      cvvPlaceholder: "CVV",
                    },
                    style: {
                      base: {
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        background: "#e5eff2",
                        color: "#101e8e",
                        opacity: "1",
                        padding: "18px 18px 18px 47px",
                        margin: "0",
                        outline: "none",
                        border: "1px solid #b6bfdc",
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "35px",
                      },
                    },
                  }}
                  cardTokenized={(e) => {
                    paymentsubmit(e);
                  }}
                >
                    <div
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        width: "100%",
                        marginTop: "30px",
                      }}
                    >
                      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                        <ExpiryDate
                          style={{ width: "90%" }}
                          className="ExpiryDate-field"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                        <p
                          style={{
                            fontSize: `${0.875}rem`,
                            fontFamily: "Segoe UI",
                            color: "#101E8E",
                            fontWeight: "700",
                          }}
                        >
                          CVV Number
                        </p>
                        <div className="cvc-image-background-color">
                          <img src={cvv} />
                        </div>

                        <Cvv type="text" className="ExpiryDate-field" />
                   <Button
                      className="pay-now"
                      onClick={() => {
                        Frames.submitCard();
                      }}
                      style={{ padding: "20px", boxShadow: "none" }}
                    >
                      PAY NOW
                    </Button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </Frames>
```

Comment: By PCC DSI regulation, payment service provider and merchant can't save CVV. Therefore, CVV won't be returned if you tokenised with Stripe.